# filter empty values when enumerating object properties

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this `ng-repeat`

```
<alert ng-repeat="(name, msg) in warnings">{{ msg }}</alert>
```

that enumerates an this object

```
$scope.warnings = {
  a: null,
  b: 'some warning',
  c: null
}
```

How would I filter warnings that have a nullvalue or are empty?

Comment: Since you have a dictionary i dont think you can use filer, you would need to use ng-if `<alert ng-repeat="(name, msg) in warnings" ng-if="msg">{{ msg }}</alert>`Change it to array and you should be good to use a filter.

Comment: @PSL this works but naomiks solution is cleaner in imho, thank you none the less

Comment: oh well i did not answer... :) btw that solution is less efficient you could just use angular.forEach directly on the object `angular.forEach($scope.warnings , function(v, k){ if(!v) delete $scope.warnings[k]; })`. And if you are `each`ing it you could event convert it to an array which works the best with ng-repeat, even the ordering you can manage with array

Comment: I now only have an `warings = {b: 'some warning' }` and use `delete` to get rid of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better tool for this in the angular lib, but you can do this

```
Object.keys($scope.warnings).forEach(function(key) {
 if (!$scope.warnings[key]) delete $scope.warnings[key]
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it's much cleaner to have just the warnings that exist on the object and delete all else.